# Exception in Kafka REST Proxy "Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema" when trying to post record with nullable key schema

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, avro, nullable, kafka-rest

I'm trying to post this message to Kafka Rest:

```
{
  "key_schema": "[\"null\",\"long\"]",
  "value_schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2\",\"namespace\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"XID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"INVOICE_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"INVOICE_DETAIL_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ADDITIONAL_INVL_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"COST_ALLOCATION_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector.GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2\"}",
  "records": [
    {
      "key": {
        "long": 140766
      },
      "value": {
        "XID": {
          "long": 29524623
        },
        "ID": {
          "long": 140766
        },
        "INVOICE_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 1
        },
        "INVOICE_DETAIL_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        },
        "ADDITIONAL_INVL_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        },
        "COST_ALLOCATION_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I've got the following error in the rest-proxy.log :

> [2019-04-11 14:25:58,991] ERROR Unhandled exception resulting in
>   internal server error response
>   (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper:38)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
>   registering Avro schema: "long" Caused by:
>   io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:
>   Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error
>   code: 409

Why it's happening??? I can't understand why

```
"key": {
        "long": 140766
      }
```

is trigerring the new schema creation?...

Btw

```
"key": null
```

is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your key value as an object.

```
"key": {
        "long": 140766
      }
```

Which does not reflect your schema:

```
"key_schema": "[\"null\",\"long\"]",
```

try this:

```
{
  "key_schema": "{\"type\":\"long\"}",
  "value_schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2\",\"namespace\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"XID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"INVOICE_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"INVOICE_DETAIL_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ADDITIONAL_INVL_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"COST_ALLOCATION_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector.GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2\"}",
  "records": [
    {
      "key": 234,
      "value": {
        "XID": {
          "long": 29524623
        },
        "ID": {
          "long": 140766
        },
        "INVOICE_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 1
        },
        "INVOICE_DETAIL_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        },
        "ADDITIONAL_INVL_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        },
        "COST_ALLOCATION_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now your key is of type long. Thus, you can only pass number next to key in your data.

However, if you want to keep your key value as an object, like you are  in your above example, then you need to define your key as a record type as well:

```
{
  "key_schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2_KEY\",\"namespace\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"long\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"]}]}",
  "value_schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2\",\"namespace\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"XID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"INVOICE_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"INVOICE_DETAIL_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ADDITIONAL_INVL_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"COST_ALLOCATION_CHANGE_COUNT\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"com.vistajet.gvedge.infrastructure.kafka.connector.GVEDGE_FI_INVOICE_TX_INFO_V2\"}",
  "records": [
    {
      "key": {
          "long": {"long": 7}
       },
      "value": {
        "XID": {
          "long": 29524623
        },
        "ID": {
          "long": 140766
        },
        "INVOICE_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 1
        },
        "INVOICE_DETAIL_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        },
        "ADDITIONAL_INVL_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        },
        "COST_ALLOCATION_CHANGE_COUNT": {
          "long": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Now back to your main question on "Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema".

The message explains self that you are trying to change your schema. However, you cannot change the same because it is not compatible with your current version of schema.

If you are sure that it is only for development, then you can change the schema compatibility level to "NONE" for now.

[image]

Then try again.

Otherwise, check what you are changing between your previous key schema and new key schema, and why it is not compatible.